# I have facing problem in deep linking using firebase in flutter app. Black screen open when opened share app link. Below I have added image

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, deep-linking, flutter-appbar

When I have open link shows the this type of image.
Firebase setup done
Also try using dynamic link package
Add required field in android manifest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.